# Plone/Sqlalchemy (saconfig) - Using .filter of a session object, how can I filter on specific fields that were chosen by a user?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, plone

I have mapped fields defined in an Interface to a mysql backend database through the use of saconfig and a declarative base.*  On my Plone Site instance, I have a form (z3c.form) that will use these fields and will be used to search for "Assets" from a mysql database based on criteria entered in several fields.  In my case, I would like to only query on fields that have data entered in them.

This is what my interface and ORMBase class look like:

```
class IAsset(Interface):
    """Interface class of an asset
    """

    Asset_ID = schema.Int(title=u"Asset ID",
                          required=False
                         )

    GPCL_Asset_ID = schema.TextLine(title=u"GPCL Asset Tracker",
                                    required=False
                                   )

    Asset_Type = schema.Int(title=u"Asset Type",
                        required=False
                       )

    Manufacturer = schema.Int(title=u"Manufacturer",
                          required=True
                         )
    Model = schema.TextLine(title=u"Serial Number",
                            required=False
                           )
    Serial_Number = schema.TextLine(title=u"Serial Number",
                                required=False
                               )


class Asset(ORMBase):
    """Class for asset
    """
    __tablename__ = 'Assets'

    Asset_ID = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(),
                                 primary_key=True,
                                 autoincrement=True
                                )
    GPCL_Asset_ID = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(255),
                                      nullable=True
                                     )

    Asset_Type = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(),
                                   nullable=False
                                  )

    Manufacturer = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer(),
                                 nullable=False
                                )

    Model = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(255),
                              nullable=True
                             )

    Serial_Number = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(255),
                                      nullable=True
                                     )
```

For testing purposes, I am using the view class of an Asset, and I have a function (current called through a template for testing purposes) that builds a dictionary based on fields that are filled out.  I also have a utility class called AssetUtils and there is a function in the class called queryAssets that accepts a dictionary containing the criteria, and returns the search results found.

```
class View(grok.View):
    """View class
    """
    ...grok definitions and fields being set for form


    def searchAssets(self):
        #get data
        ....

        criteria = {}
        #build dictionary
        #if field (i.e. GPCL_Asset_ID) is not empty, add to the dictionary GPCL_Asset_ID:valueEnteredByUser

        assets = queryAssets(criteria)


class AssetUtils(grok.GlobalUtility):
    def queryAssets(searchCriteria):
```

I have a session object defined at the root of the class.  In queryAssets I would like to use session.query(Asset).filter() to query the Assets table.  The problem I am having though is figuring out what to pass into filter().  I know how to use the query function, like session.query(Asset).filter(GPCL_Asset_ID.like('D%'),Manufacturer==15).
However, say Serial Number was present, but GPCL_Asset_ID was not, so I would like to use .filter(Serial_Number.like("EX12%")), and then another case where only Model and Manufacturer were present. .filter(Model.like("A3%"),Manufacturer==32)

So my question is, how can I make it so that .filter filters on fields that were defined/chosen in the dictionary passed into the queryAssets function I have, as opposed to fields being pre-defined in the .filter function?

*I am following along with the book "Professional Plone 4 Development" by Martin Aspeli, chapter 12 and a slideshow presentation (http://www.slideshare.net/jbellis/pycon-2010-sqlalchemy-tutorial) - Slide 27, 29. Compared to the slideshow, I am actually using saconfig as found in Martin Aspeli's book.

Comment: Not clear reading your question: have you already created a view with the HTML form you are tatliking about (using plain ZPT or by z3c.form, or other)?
Can you enhance the question with additional information about the form?

Comment: I attempted to rewrite the question to make it clearer.  I apologize that my question's details were confusing/unorganized before.

Comment: Also, I am currently calling the function searchAssets in the view template of an asset for testing purposes for now.  So I am trying various scenarios such as assets = queryAssets({GPCL_Asset_ID:'D231'}), which would lead to results = session.query(GPCL_Asset_ID.like("D231%"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your class, from the `searchAssets` method you simply need to access the `self.request.form` dict-like object and read all the data submitted (by HTTP GET or POST) to that view.

You can then build your list of filters parameters like:

```
params = []
if 'param1' in self.request.form:
    params.append(Asset_ID.like(...))
if ...

session.query(*params)
```

Comment: What should I pass into the session.query.filter function once I obtain the data the user entered into the fields?  Like if in one case GPCL_Asset_ID is present, but in another case only Model is present?

Comment: Enhanced the question (it's more a pure Python/SQLAchemy issue).
SQLAlchemy filter/query always returns objects that you can collect and pass to method later.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is what I was looking for.  Also, I'll be more careful with details in the future.